# ASP.NET CORE DI - Resolve IDbConnection from EF Core's Database.GetDbConnection()

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.2, ef-core-2.2

In my application I use EF Core `DbContext` at most of the places where data access is required. Also wherever underlying connection is required, I just inject `DbContext` and get the connection using `DbContext.Database.GetDbConnection()`.
In one of the class libraries- (where ef core context is not possible to inject), I need to inject IDbConnection to get db access working.

I tried

```
services.AddScoped<IDbConnection>(sp=>sp.GetRequiredService<MyContext>().Database.GetDbConnection())
```

but it throws stackoverflow exception.

Currently, I'm using following-

```
services.AddScoped<IDbConnection>(sp=>new SqlConnection(connStringFromConfig))
```

which works but I'm searching for an alternative that can benefit from the connection resiliency/ExecutionStrategy(when EnableRetryOnFailures used) which comes built-in with DbContext's underlying connection.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What is `GetConnection()`? Do you mean `GetDbConnecttion()`?

Comment: yes. edited.thanks.

Comment: Ok, how you register your db context? Because `services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options...).AddScoped<IDbConnection>(sp=>sp.GetRequiredService<MyContext>().Database.GetDbConnection())` works for me (no stack overflow exception).

Comment: So it turned out that the class where I wanted to inject IDbConnection resolved using MyContext, itself was one of the dependencies of MyContext. Not sure why circular dependency exception was not thrown by .net core's DI framework. So this class is at the lowest level in dependency graph(sits in framework/shared library where concrete context cannot be injected).

Answer (score 1):

[Connection resiliency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-resiliency) automatically retries failed database commands. It is a feature of Entity Framework Core and can be configured typically in `OnConfiguring` method of `DbContext` or in Startup.cs in `ConfigureServices` method.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder
        .UseSqlServer("<connection string>", options => options.EnableRetryOnFailure());
}
```

This feature is related to EntityFramework, it is not directly a feature of `SqlConnection`. When you use `SqlConnection` (or the interface `IDbConnection`) in your project, and do not use `DbContext`, you would probably need to implement your own retry.